# Return some values from a database query

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, class

When an user is logging in I am doing this:

```
public static User GetUser(string nickname, string password)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Nickname = @nickname AND Password = @password";
        command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@nickname", nickname));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@password", password));
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserID"]);
            int IsAdmin = Convert.ToInt32(reader["IsAdmin"]);
            int IsActivated = Convert.ToInt32(reader["IsActivated"]);
            string Nickname = reader["Nickname"].ToString();
            string FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
            string LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
            string Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
            string Password = reader["Password"].ToString();
            string DateRegistered = reader["DateRegistered"].ToString();

            User user = new User(UserID, IsAdmin, IsActivated, null, Nickname, FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, DateRegistered);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
    return ????
}
```

I want to return the values which are read. But what do I need to fill instead of the ????

I was doing it with a `List<>` and a foreach loop, but someone suggested me to do this!

Comment: Return your instance of User?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Don't have that possibility...

Comment: Because you put the declaration in the Try so it's stuck in that scope. Just define User before the try, assign it in try and return the instance (which can be Null if your transaction fails). I mean, your method return type is a User, you define a User, the link is easy to make.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Then it says: "Use of unassigned local variable 'user'

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Ah it works! with User user = null; before the try thnx!

Comment: I suggest you get out of the habit of ignoring exceptions. Use `try {...} finally {connection.Close();}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user variable is out of scope in the loop.  You only expect one user, I would do this:

```
User user=null;
if (reader.Read())
{
        int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserID"]);
        int IsAdmin = Convert.ToInt32(reader["IsAdmin"]);
        int IsActivated = Convert.ToInt32(reader["IsActivated"]);
        string Nickname = reader["Nickname"].ToString();
        string FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
        string LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
        string Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
        string Password = reader["Password"].ToString();
        string DateRegistered = reader["DateRegistered"].ToString();

        user = new User(UserID, IsAdmin, IsActivated, null, Nickname, FirstName, 
}
else 
{

  // handle error no user
}

if (reader.Read())
{
   // handle more than one user error
}

// other stuff close connect and reader etc.

return user;
```

Comment: Do you recommend me to do this with public User GetUser() or public List<User> GetUser() ?

Comment: This is code for a function that returns `User` as you asked.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes it does, but wanted to know what u prefer ;p

Comment: @xVizzi - It depends on what you program is doing -- if you expect only one user then the code should only return one user -- everything else is an err.

Comment: I like your answer, but I would note that it's the database which should ensure there are no duplicate users, not the code.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - It doesn't look like he is selecting on a unique id (userID) here, but on the nickname and password.  So I think two users with the same nickname and password would pose a problem with this design.  The design issue is at the application level not the DB, IMHO.